# what do they mean with "not all code paths return a value"?

Tags: c#

--> Error 'Minesweeper.Game.Gewonnen()': not all code paths return a value.

What am I doin' wrong?

```
public bool Gewonnen()
{

  for (int y = 0; y < _boolArray.GetLength(0); y++)
  {
    for (int x = 0; x < _boolArray.GetLength(1); x++)
    {
      if (_boolArray[x, y] == false)
        return false;

      else
        return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you only want to check the first member? Your code is only checking `_boolArray[0, 0]` and immediately returning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That means not all possible execution paths returns value. In you example loop may not be executed even once (when `_boolArray` length is 0) and if that happens your method would not return anything. Add `return false` at the end of method:

```
public bool Gewonnen() 
{
    for (int y = 0; y < _boolArray.GetLength(0); y++)
    {
         for (int x = 0; x < _boolArray.GetLength(1); x++)
         {
              if (_boolArray[x, y] == false)
                  return false;
              else
                  return true;
         }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks, it works. But now I have another problem
This is in my Main Class:

      while (spiel.Gewonnen = false)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Y Koordinate?");
        int yeingabe = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("X Koordinate?");
        int xeingabe = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        spiel.EingabeWeiterLeiter(yeingabe, xeingabe, anzahlMinen);
      }

--> Error: Cannot assign to 'Gewonnen' because it is a 'method group'

it should repeat the game loop, untill the game is won

Comment: Two problems. First, it's `spiel.Gewonnen()`, not `spiel.Gewonnen`. Second, it's `==`, not `=`. You can also write that as `while (!spiel.Gewonnen()) { /* do stuff */ }`.

Comment: Please create another question because reading code from comment is a pain.

Answer (score 1):

gzaxx solution will compile.
Anyway, I'm not sure that it is what you want because in that case it will always return after the first iteration (if any).
Here is another try (I hope it helps):

```
public bool Gewonnen()
{

  for (int y = 0; y < _boolArray.GetLength(0); y++)
  {
    for (int x = 0; x < _boolArray.GetLength(1); x++)
    {
      if (_boolArray[x, y] == false)
        return false;
    }
  }

  return true;  //this mean _boolArray has no false value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume for example that your first for-loop would at some point be something like:

```
for (int y = 0; y < _boolArray.GetLength(0); y++) { }
```

and at that point in time your _boolArray has a length of 0. It would then result in

```
for (int y = 0; y < 0; y++) { }
```

That means it is instantly done with this piece of code, going to the end of the loop. But wait: this function was supposed to return a boolean value, and there is no return whatsoever.

That in a nutshell is what "not all code paths return a value" means. You are not allowed to have any (unlikely?) combination of values that would make you end the function without returning the a value of the type mentoin in the function (`boolean` in this case)